# Should Spring @Repository follow JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to store data in HashMap<> or ArrayList<> without database connection.
Also, I want to create a class that manages data such as updating or getting data by conditions.

In this case, is it appropriate to create and use a Repository without using a JpaRepository?
Or is there another way that is appropriate?

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository  {
    private List<Product> productList; // = new ArrayList<>();

    public Product getProductByid(int id) { ... };
    public boolean updateProduct() { ... };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look at Spring Data Key Value documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/keyvalue/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

Spring Data Key Value is for Spring applications that use key-value stores.

Here is simple example: http://www.henryxi.com/spring-data-keyvalue-example

**EDIT:** As **doctore** correctly stated in comment, this example is more suitable for your case: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-key-value

Comment: The recommended choice is right but not the included example. The following is a more suitable one: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-key-value